# SQL check is zero or null

Tags: t-sql, conditional-statements

Hi i have some problem

Need to check is null or zero by column if something wrong doing some algorithm

This is a table:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
1        0      3376    0
2       600     null    14468.5714
3       null    0       0
4       600     3376    null
```

`COALESCE` doesn't work with zero "0" value, `case` its too huge

need to realize some of that

```
, CAST(COALESCE(col2, (col3/7), (col4/30)) as money) col2
, CAST(COALESCE(col3, (col2*7), (col4/30*7))as money) col3
, CAST(COALESCE(col4, (col3/7*30),(col2*30))as money) col4
```

how to solve this in fastest way. ThanX

Comment: Are you saying you need to differentiate between encountering 0 vs null?  "null or 0" could be interpreted ambiguously I think.

Answer (score 7):

While COALESCE allows you to replace a NULL with a specific value, NULLIF will allow you to replace a specific value with a NULL. You could use the latter on 0 and end up with something like this:

```
, CAST(
    COALESCE(
      NULLIF(col2, 0),
      NULLIF(col3, 0) / 7,
      NULLIF(col4, 0) / 30
    ) AS money
  ) AS col2
, CAST(
    COALESCE(
      NULLIF(col3, 0),
      NULLIF(col2, 0) * 7,
      NULLIF(col4, 0) / 30 * 7)
    ) AS money
  ) AS col3
, CAST(
    COALESCE(
      NULLIF(col4, 0),
      NULLIF(col3, 0) / 7 * 30,
      NULLIF(col2, 0) * 30
    ) AS money
  ) AS col4
```

Still rather long, if you asked me, but definitely shorter than using CASEs. The last NULLIF in each expression might be unnecessary, I left them there for consistency. Perhaps you could add a fourth argument of `0` everywhere, just to make sure the result is never a NULL.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a `CASE` condition like

```
CASE WHEN col2 is not null and col2 <> 0 THEN your_calculation
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do a subquery with CASE statement to check for zero and return NULL.
your current query can then be run on the subquery.

I see that using case would be ugly as you have 3 expressions in COALESCE

```
SELECT
 CAST(COALESCE(col2  , (col3/7), (col4/30)) as money) col2
, CAST(COALESCE(col3, (col2*7), (col4/30*7))as money) col3
, CAST(COALESCE(col4, (col3/7*30),(col2*30))as money) col4 
from 
( SELECT case when col2 =0 then NULL else col2 end as col2,
  case when col3 =0 then NULL else col3 end as col3,
  case when col4 =0 then NULL else col4 end as col4
from Table1) T
```